# Show that an axiom in Hilbert Calculus is valid

Tags: logic

Consider the axiom in Hilbert Calculus:
$$(\forall x(A\to B))\to (A\to\forall x B)$$

Where $x$ is not free in $A$

I want to show that for evry structure $M$ and for every interpertation $\rho$, the axiom is valid.

So if the prefix is false then all the axiom is true. Therefore, lets assume that $$[|\forall x(A\to B)|]^M_\rho = t$$

By definition of $\forall$ that means that for every $a\in D^M$:
$$[|A\to B|]^M_{\rho[a/x]} = t$$

note: the notation above means that we update the interpretation $\rho$ such that $\rho(x) = a$.

From here I think I should reach to the conclusion that:

$$[|A\to \forall x B|]^M_\rho = t$$

Now, I am not sure how to explain it exactly. We know that $x$ isn't free in $A$ (assumption), but it doesn't mean it doesn't appear on $A$. $A$ could be something like $A\equiv \forall x.A$ - But is that even a valid formula? I am a little bit confused about how to explain the last step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It holds generally that if $x$ is not free in $A$, then $[\![A]\!]^M_\rho = [\![A]\!]^M_{\rho[a/x]}$ for all $M$, $\rho$, $a$. If you don't already know that, you should start by proving it; it isn't hard to do by structural induction on $A$.

Then for your main proof, divide into cases according to the truth value $[\![A]\!]^M_\rho$

Comment: could $A$ be something like $\forall x R(x)$? If so,  $[|A|]^M_{\rho[a/x]}$ wouldn't make any sense. Would it?

Comment: @LiorGolan: I'm pretty sure your definition of what $[\![\forall x. B]\!]^M_\rho$ means ought to handle that -- in the sense that it can be seen not to depend on what $\rho(x)$ is.